# About "Preparation for a non-academic career"

Tags: discussion, support

I was just about to ask a question having to do with "Preparation for a non-academic career". Specifically, I was going to ask how an academic can tell what's the salary range for a potential research position in the hi-tech industry (generally or in some region). Noticing the interdiction in the tour, I didn't ask that - but is it really off-topic? I mean, it is a problem mostly unique to academic researches.

Comment: I don't see that you've asked it yet, so I'll comment here.  There are sites that provide such information, e.g. glass door.  You might find the information you need there.

Answer (score 6):

That is intended to discourage people outside of academia from asking questions about "what's the best degree to become a sailboat repairman?" Historically, we have tended to allow questions about where academics can find employment other industries.

To that extent, ask away, says I.

Comment: I will also note the part in the "on topic" help page: "anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent fields."